# Verification email is unclear, has visual glitches

Tags: feature-request, bug, email, email-verification

I just changed the email used with my account to receive emails. This is what the verification email looked like:

[image: The email — read description below]

There are a number of problems with the email:

- The title is "Email Verification - Science Fiction & Fantasy Stack Exchange". There is a box reading "To receive Science Fiction & Fantasy emails, confirm your email address. This is unclear—**changing the address for receiving messages from the site on one site changes all of them but the title and the box make it sound otherwise.**
- The top half of the box with the button to verify the email address has been severed from the bottom half.
- There's a stray "verifica" sitting where the top half apparently once was.

The visual glitches are the same in Chrome and Firefox on desktop. They don’t occur in the iOS Mail app.

**Please fix these and make it clear that this affects all Stack Exchange sites you have connected accounts on.**

Comment: Just so we can rule out addons - that looks like gmail, does it do the same in inconito mode? Any extensions?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I have no Chrome extensions, as I don’t use the browser. It happens in Firefox in private browsing.